# commiting new changes to migrate command - sequelize-cli Nodejs

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have trouble with sequelize-cli in nodejs. suppose we define a new model with this command :

```
sequelize model:create --name User --attributes username:string,password:string,email:string,role:string,mobile:string
```

as you know this command make a migration file in migrations directory.

and with this command I can migrate my model to the database :

```
sequelize db:migrate
```

so this is ok . but what about my new changes in my model? how can I commit my new changes to database ?I need a proper way for that. 
in django framework there were two basic commands :

makemigrations => for detecting new changes

migrate => for commiting to database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `migration:create` CLI command (https://github.com/sequelize/cli) to generate new migration file and edit this file manually to make the changes you need.

Comment: tnx for reply . I did this command with --name  . I must compare the old migrates with new migration file ? and put my new changes there?